# Check input box for number or text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input

I'm implementing logic to use a url for a query parameter, based on whether the user enters a series of numbers or letters. If the user enters a number, the first `urlLocation` should be used, otherwise the second one should be used. Trying to use a regex for the first one, but I'm not sure how to implement that one correctly.

```
<input id="imageid" type="text" />

if ($("#imageid").val() == '/[^0-9\.]/') {
    var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation;
} else {
    var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/guid/" + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation;
}
```

JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/nUBZk/2/)

Comment: What you have there is a string comparison, not a regex.

Comment: `/^\d+$/.test($("#imageid").val())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `isNaN` to check for a number or not:

```
var val = $("#imageid").val();
if (isNaN(val)) {
    //Not a number!
} else {
    //Number!
}
```

Comment: Yep. http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/422jfv93/2/ for example.

Comment: Ah, I had tried that previously, but incorrectly. That works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, although you'd probably want to change it to include a star.

Your other option could be to convert it to a number and see if it is still equal to itself -

```
var val = $("#imageid").val();
if (+val == val) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input id="imageId" type="text" />
<input type="submit">
</form>

$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(){
if (/^[\d]+$/.test($("#imageId").val())) {
var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation;
} else {
var urlLocation = "http://www.url.com/rest/v1/cms/story/guid/" + imageid.value + "/orientation/" + orientation;
}
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/vOYqWM)

Regex Explanation:

```
^[\d]+$
-------

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «^»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «[\d]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator) «$»
```